On a simple alternative correction to Roos' theorem on $\varprojlim^1$
Here is a discussion about an incorrect theorem of Roos, later corrected, some counterexamples and so on. Reading over this, I was a bit shocked because it contradicted something from Weibel's textbook and my own notes. In an effort to salvage work based on these notes, I came up with a "different" criterion. I'm asking here to (i) triple check it is correct and (ii) see if it essentially the same thing as the criteria proposed in the corrected statements (which are all in papers I don't have access to).
My proposal:

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be an Abelian category with all limits of $\Bbb N$-indexed towers and [this is the correction] where $\varprojlim X_\bullet\to X_1$ is an epimorphism whenever $\cdots\to X_n\to X_{n-1}\to\cdots\to X_1$ is a $\Bbb N$-indexed tower all of whose arrows are epimorphisms.
Then the right derived functor of $\varprojlim$ (on towers) exists, has dimension (at most) one and any Mittag-Leffler tower has vanishing $\varprojlim^1$.

I think of this condition as an axiom of countable choice. All it says is that yes, we can just choose 'lifts' infinitely many times; it feels like a nonemptiness condition too. As an aside, I wonder if there is theory, as there is in topos theory, of choice-like principles, Zorn's lemma and so on for Abelian categories.
I have proven this proposal below. Is this a known alternative? Is it stronger or equivalent to the one in Roos' (or Gabber's? I'm not sure who did what) correction?
I note that in the appendix to Neeman's book on triangulated categories, it is shown that if $\mathscr{A}$ satisfies has countable products, satisfies $\mathsf{AB4}^\ast$ and (this is their correction) enough projectives, then the Mittag-Leffler theory works. However, I note that Neeman's condition also implies mine, (and mine implies existence and exactness of countable products) so mine is weaker and offers an improvement on their result in the countable case - so my question about comparing this to other criteria (and whether it was previously known) still stands.

My proof:
It seems to me the only subtle point, where Roos, Weibel and my younger self seemingly all went wrong, lies in verifying $\varprojlim^1X_\bullet=0$ if $X_\bullet$ is a tower whose arrows are all epimorphisms. The rest of the argument from Weibel works unchanged. I will present the full argument anyway, for completeness.
Fix notation; if $X_\bullet$ is a $\Bbb N$-indexed tower, write $\theta_{i,j}$ for the map $X_i\to X_j$, $j\le i$. Say a tower is epimorphic if every $\theta_{i,j}$ is an epimorphism.
Considering the tower formed by $\bigoplus_{k=1}^n X_k$ for some objects $(X_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$, it is clear that $\mathscr{A}$ has all $\Bbb N$-indexed products. But I claim firstly that in a category satisfying my conditions, the countable products not only exist but are also exact.
Let $(X_i)_{i\in\Bbb N},(Y_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$ be objects and $(f_i:X_i\twoheadrightarrow Y_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$ be epimorphisms. Now and at the bottom of the post, in very similar ways, I will use Mac Lane's rules of the diagram chase, laid out in Categories for the Working Mathematician and I will use that notation freely. A very key point is that these do not easily extend to infinitary diagram chases, so it is easy to go wrong.
Let $y\in_m\prod_iY_i$, represented by some $y:Z\to\prod_iY_i$. $\pi_1y$ lifts against the epimorphism $f_1$ and we find some epimorphism $\theta_{1,0}:Z_1\twoheadrightarrow Z$ and $x_1:Z_1\to X_1$, that $f_1x_1=\pi_1y\theta_{1,0}$. Now $\pi_2y\theta_{1,0}\in_m Y_2$ lifts against the epimorphism $f_2$ and we find an epi $\theta_{2,1}:Z_2\twoheadrightarrow Z_1$, $x_2:Z_2\to X_2$, that $f_2x_2=\pi_2y\theta_{2,0}:=\pi_2y\theta_{1,0}\theta_{2,1}$ and so on. We find an epimorphic tower $Z_\bullet$ with data of $x_n:Z_n\to X_n$ such that $f_nx_n=\pi_ny\theta_{n,0}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Now if $L:=\varprojlim Z$, we have an element $x:L\to\prod_i X_i$ with $\pi_ix:=x_i\circ\theta_i$ and $\pi_j(\prod_i f_i)x=f_j\pi_jx=f_jx_j\theta_j=\pi_jy\theta_{j,0}\theta_j=\pi_j\circ y\theta$, if $\theta:L\twoheadrightarrow Z$ is the only possible map, equal to $\theta_{k,0}\theta_k$ for all $k$. Using the hypothesis, it is an epimorphism. Letting $j$ range, we realise $(\prod_i f_i)x=y\theta$. In other words, any member $y\in_m\prod_i Y_i$ has $y\equiv(\prod_if_i)x$ for some $x\in_m\prod_i X_i$; by the rules, it follows $\prod_i f_i$ is an epimorphism as desired and $\mathscr{A}$ satisfies $AB4^\ast_\omega$.
Now we have exact countable products, we define $\varprojlim^1$ in the well-known manner; for any tower $X_\bullet$, it is easy to check the limit cone $(\varprojlim X_\bullet\to X_n)$ and $(\ker\Delta\subset\prod_i X_i\to X_n)$ share the same universal property where $\Delta:\prod_i X_i\to\prod_i X_i$ is given by $\pi_i\Delta:=\pi_i-\theta_{i+1,i}\pi_{i+1}$. Moreover if $X_\bullet\to Y_\bullet$ is a map of towers, the map $\prod_i X_i\to\prod_i Y_i$ commutes with the two $\Delta$ maps and the induced arrow on the kernels is identifiable with the limiting arrow $\varprojlim X_\bullet\to\varprojlim Y_\bullet$. We define $\varprojlim^1X_\bullet:=\mathrm{coker}(\Delta)$ and by the same comment about commuting with the $\Delta$ maps, it is functorial and by exactness of countable products and a simple application of the Snake lemma, $(\varprojlim,\varprojlim^1,0,0,0,\cdots)$ assembles to a cohomological $\delta$-functor.
Assume for now that $\varprojlim^1$ effaces epimorphic towers (I will come back to this point of course). Then it is a universal $\delta$-functor i.e. reasonably called the right derived functor, as any tower $E$ embeds into the epimorphic tower $\prod_{k=1}^n k_\ast E_k$ thus the $\delta$-functor is effaceable, where $k_\ast A$ is the tower constant to $A$ at and above index $k$, and zero everywhere below; $\cdots\to A=A=A=\cdots=A=A\to0\to0\to0\to\cdots$. Each $k_\ast E_k$ is epimorphic, and the product is again because I assume countable products are exact.
The Mittag-Leffler condition is that for all $n$ there is $m_n\in\Bbb N$ such that for all $k\ge m_n$, the canonical map $\mathrm{im}(\theta_{k+n,n})\subset\mathrm{im}(\theta_{m_n+n,n})$ is an isomorphism ("the images stabilise in finite time"). The trivial Mittag-Leffler condition is that this common, stable image is zero.
Suppose the tower $X_\bullet$ satisfies the trivial Mittag-Leffler condition. Without loss, take $(m_n)_n$ to be an increasing sequence; if $m_n$ 'works', so does any $k\ge m_n$, so this is ok. It turns out $\Delta$ actually is a split epimorphism in this case. Consider $\gamma:\prod_i X_i\to\prod_i X_i$, defined by $\pi_i\gamma=\sum_{j=0}^{m_i-1}\theta_{i+j,i}\pi_{i+j}$. Then: $$\begin{align}\pi_i\Delta\gamma&=\pi_i+\sum_{j=1}^{m_i-1}\theta_{i+j,i}\pi_{i+j}-\sum_{j=0}^{m_{i+1}-1}\theta_{i+j+1,i}\pi_{i+j+1}\\&=\pi_i+\sum_{j=1}^{m_i-1}\theta_{i+j,i}\pi_{i+j}-\sum_{j=1}^{m_i-1}\theta_{i+j,i}\pi_{i+j}-\sum_{j=m_i}^{m_{i+1}}\underset{0}{\underbrace{\theta_{i+j,i}}}\pi_{i+j}\\&=\pi_i\end{align}$$By the universal property of products, $\Delta\gamma=1$ results. In particular, $\varprojlim^1X_\bullet=0$ as $\Delta$ is forced to be an epimorphism.
Now if $A_\bullet$ satisfies the general Mittag-Leffler condition, define $B_n:=\mathrm{im}(\theta_{m_n+n,n})\subseteq A_n$. If $n\ge2$, because $\theta_{n,n-1}|_{B_n}\circ\theta_{m_n+n,n}$ factors through $B_{n-1}$ and $\theta_{m_n+n,n}:A_{m_n+n}\twoheadrightarrow B_n$ is an epimorphism, it follows $\theta_{n,n-1}|_{B_n}:B_n\to A_{n-1}$ factors through $B_{n-1}$ and moreover (stable images) as $A_{m_n+1+n-1}\twoheadrightarrow\mathrm{im}(\theta_{m_n+1+n-1,n-1})\cong B_{n-1}$ is an epimorphism ($m_n+1>m_{n-1}$), it follows $B_n\to B_{n-1}$ is an epimorphism. We see a subtower $B_\bullet$ of $A_\bullet$ arises where $B_\bullet$ is epimorphic, and also that $A_\bullet/B_\bullet$ satisfies the trivial Mittag-Leffler condition as eventually the maps $A_k\to A_n$ factor through $B_n$ and $A_k/B_k\to A_n/B_n$ vanishes. Then there is an exact sequence: $0=\varprojlim^1B_\bullet\to\varprojlim^1A_\bullet\to\varprojlim^1(A_\bullet/B_\bullet)=0$, forcing $\varprojlim^1A_\bullet=0$ as desired.
The only remaining thing to do is check $\varprojlim^1$ effaces epimorphic towers.
Fix an epimorphic tower $X_\bullet$. We want $\Delta$ to be an epimorphism. Let $x\in_m\prod_i X_i$ be a member, with domain $Y$. $-\pi_1x\in_m X_1$ lifts against the epimorphism $X_2\twoheadrightarrow X_1$ up to equivalence; explicitly, (working implicitly with this is dangerous in the infinite case..) there is $\lambda_{1,0}:Y_1\twoheadrightarrow Y$ and $y_2:Y_1\to X_2$ so that $\theta_{2,1}y_2=-\pi_1x\lambda_{1,0}$. I will inductively build an epimorphic tower $Y_\bullet$ with structure maps $\lambda$ and data of $y_n:Y_{n-1}\to X_n$ satisfying $y_n\lambda_{n,n-1}-\theta_{n+1,n}y_{n+1}=\pi_nx\lambda_{n,0}$. The induction is fairly trivial, we just keep pulling back. To get the $(n+1)$th terms given the first $n$, we just consider that $y_n-\pi_nx\lambda_{n-1,0}\in_m X_n$ lifts against the epimorphism $\theta_{n+1,n}$ and we get some object, call it $Y_n$, and an epimorphism, call it $\lambda_{n,n-1}:Y_n\twoheadrightarrow Y_{n-1}$, and $y_{n+1}:Y_n\to X_{n+1}$ such that $\theta_{n+1,n}y_{n+1}=(y_n-\pi_nx\lambda_{n-1,0})\circ\lambda_{n,n-1}$ and of course $\lambda_{n,0}$ is defined as $\lambda_{n-1,0}\lambda_{n,n-1}$ (or indeed $\lambda_{m,0}\lambda_{n,m}$ for any $0\le m\le n$) so we are good.
With these data constructed, the key point is that considering $\prod_i Y_i$ is no good; we must consider $L:=\varprojlim Y_\bullet$. Write $\lambda_j:L\to Y_j$ for the canonical projections. My hypothesis is that $\lambda_1$ is an epimorphism. $\lambda:=\lambda_{1,0}\circ\lambda_1:L\twoheadrightarrow Y$ is also epi.
We now construct a member $y$ of $\prod_i X_i$ simply via the map $L\to\prod_i X_i$, $\pi_iy:=y_i\lambda_{i-1}$ for $i\ge2$ and $\pi_1y:=0$. I claim $\Delta y=x\lambda$ i.e. the member $x$ is equivalent ($\lambda$ is epi) to $\Delta y$ for some member $y$. According to the rules, this is all we needed to do to prove $\Delta$ is an epimorphism (you can even take $x=\mathrm{id}$ but working with 'elements' is more notationally friendly).
For $i=1$, $\pi_1\circ\Delta y=0-\theta_{2,1}\pi_2y=-\theta_{2,1}y_2\lambda_1=\pi_1x\lambda_{1,0}\lambda_1=\pi_1\circ x\lambda$ as desired.
For $i\ge2$, $\pi_i\circ\Delta y=y_i\lambda_{i-1}-\theta_{i+1,i}y_{i+1}\lambda_i=(y_i\lambda_{i,i-1}-\theta_{i+1,i}y_{i+1})\circ\lambda_i=\pi_i x\lambda_{i,0}\circ\lambda_i=\pi_i\circ x\lambda$ as desired. Compatibility of the $\lambda_i$ with the $\lambda_{i,j}$ is essential; this is what made me think of the limit criterion, when I realised taking $L:=\prod_i Y_i$ doesn't work.
So, we are done. The arbitrary member $x$ of the codomain of $\Delta$ is equivalent to $\Delta y$ for some $y$ a member of its domain; $\Delta$ is an epimorphism, and $\varprojlim^1X_\bullet=0$; $\varprojlim^1$ effaces epimorphic towers.

As an aside, while reading a paper of Spaltenstein I found I had to prove for myself a similar kind of thing for Abelian groups, where now the towers are indexed by arbitrary ordinals. Does anyone know if we can reasonably construct a $\varprojlim^1$ for towers of greater length? or for suitable, 'continuous' towers?

Sure, there are Springer Lecture Notes of .C. U. Jensen: Les foncteurs dérivés de lim
et leurs applications en théorie des
modules. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1972. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 25

@FShrike Barry Mitchell studied ordinal-indexed higher derived limits in the last two sections of "Rings with many objects" (1972), and showed that, for an ordinal $\alpha$ of cardinality aleph-$n$, the $(n+2)$th derived lim, and all the derived limits above it, vanish. The case $n=0$ is the classical theorem that sequential derived $lim^i$ vanishes for all $i>1$. If you formulate the right analogue of the Mittag-Leffler condition for ordinal-indexed limits, the ML condition ensures that the topmost possibly-nontrivial derived lim vanishes.

My thanks to you both

@user509184 Should that be Rings with several objects?

@NoahSchweber Yes, that's what I should have written, thanks!
